# `apt-get` autocompletion of package name is broken

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, auto-completion

At some moment, the `apt-get install` autocomplete was broken. It was very useful to me to see the names of packages available for installation when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

For example, if I would press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key after `sudo apt-get install ruby`, all packages starting with `ruby` would be displayed, such as `ruby-mysql`, `ryby-dev`, etc.

Instead of this behavior, if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, I get a list of directories, as I get when I use `cd` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

How to repair this autocomplete?

Comment: What package you were trying to find? Is it available via apt-cache search mypkg I am using Kubuntu on Oneiric i see it working well.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

As stated in the comments to the other answer, first make sure that `bash-completion` is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install bash-completion
```

and [apparently for @diapir](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86375/apt-get-autocomplete-package-name-is-broken#comment152858_86640), it helped to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion
```

However, for me, the problem was not that bash-completion was not installed or broken, the problem was that I had accidently deleted my `.bashrc` file. You can get a new one by copying it from `/etc/skel`:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Comment: Thanks, the bashrc tip solved the problem for me as well. The use of `sudo` on the `chmod` command is unnecessary though, right?

Comment: the file located in `/etc/` is `0644/-rw-r--r--` with user:group = `root:root`, and when copied to your user folder, will automatically go to user:user

Comment: cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/ helped me solve this problem.

Comment: Reinstall and copied /etc/skel/.bashrc helped  me, thank you!

Answer (score 38):

Type the following command:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Look for these lines:

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
# if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
# fi
```

Uncomment some lines, to make it look like this:

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Save, close terminal, then reopen it.

I have this issue after installing 13.04, and that's how I resolve it.

Comment: this was the only thing that worked for me. thank you.

Comment: Worked for me on Elementary OS LoKi

Answer (score 12):

Note that output of this command:

```
apt-config dump | grep "Dir::Cache"
```

Should be something like this:

```
Dir::Cache "var/cache/apt";
Dir::Cache::archives "archives/";
Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "srcpkgcache.bin";
Dir::Cache::pkgcache "pkgcache.bin";
```

If value of `Dir::Cache::pkgcache` is empty, apt will not be able to auto complete package names. Take a look at your `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` files and search for this key to be sure that it's not set to empty string.

```
grep -r pkgcache /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/
```

To fix it comment out all lines of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean`

```
# DPkg::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };
# APT::Update::Post-Invoke { "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true"; };
# Dir::Cache::pkgcache ""; Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";
```

and then

```
apt update
```

Also take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1026978/187689).

Comment: Looks like this (and the link) is the correct answer if you have this issue inside a docker container.

Comment: this still works tysm! just do `rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean`

Answer (score 4):

Download the latest stable release of `bash-completion` from `http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/`, and from within the downloaded directory use the following commands to build and install it:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

If you don't have `make` installed, you can install it with the `build-essential` package:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

After successful installation, insert the following lines to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
  . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: `bash-completion` is in packages - is there any reason you did it manually? The package should do pretty much exactly this :)

Comment: :) as always, sitting, reading manuals, configure, and then it turns out that this soft is exists in the repository

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash-completion` did it for me.

Comment: @diapir, I have the same problem, but only reinstall does not working. I have to apply the lines in `bashrc` file.