# Terminal autocompletion 'tab' not working as intended?

Tags: command-line, auto-completion

I know this has been discussed on other posts but my problem does not seem to be fully resolved and I do not have permission to add a comment to those posts yet :(

listed on help.ubuntu.com > UsingTheTerminal > Save on Typing:

> Tab: "It autocompletes any commands or filenames".

After following the advise from [apt-get autocomplete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86375/apt-get-autocomplete) I get results after pressing tab twice but no auto completion for commands or files. Running Xubuntu 13.04.

Comment: it completes file name only if the initials you are providing is unique , and dont have any other possible file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it completes file name only if the initials you are providing is unique , and don’t have any other possible file name:

Suppose you have two file `file1expo` and `file2expo` in working directory-

then using `gedit file<<tab>>` will not work because it has two possible outcomes, where as `gedit file1<<tab>>` will work.

If you want to list all the files starting with initials like `xaa` then simply use

```
ls "xaa"
```

it will show all the files names with starting characters  `xaa`.

Comment: @Sushantip606 Thank you for making that clear. My bad haste - it does state this in help.ubuntu: "A very useful feature. It autocompletes any commands or filenames, (if there's only one option), or else gives you a list of options.
" I

Comment: if you want to know something else then please make another question and if answer has explained what you were expecting then just accept it as answer.

Answer (score 11):

To enable smart completion

Using sudo and your favorite editor, edit your `/etc/bash.bashrc` file.

Uncomment the following lines, by removing the # in the beginning of the lines:

```
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
# . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

Now you can use tab completion to power your way through commands.

Answer (score 3):

This can be frustrating, that is for sure!  One quick and easy workaround would to just use `bash` instead of `sh`.

You may be defaulting to using `/bin/sh` as your shell instead of `/bin/bash`. Personally I like `bash` better as it has Tab-autocompletion turned on out of the box.

Check to determine your shell:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh               <-- this may be your issue
```

Launch `bash` to ensure this fixes the issue:

```
bash
```

Now try the Tab-autocompletion. If it works, then change your default shell from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` using the `chsh` (change shell) command for that user:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash USERNAME
```

Logout and log back in. Now all new shells will Tab-autocomplete.