# How to make tab completion append slash for directory symlinks?

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

My `~/Documents` directory is a symlink:

```
nathan@nathan-desktop:~$ stat Documents
  File: Documents -> /mnt/nathan/extended/Documents
```

If I want to `cd` into the directory, I can type:

<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>
 <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd>

...and tab completion will append `uments` to the end of `cd Doc` as expected. However, it does *not* append a trailing `/`, even though the symlink points to a directory.

Is there a way to make Bash do that?

Comment: That seems like it's a ZSH thing, not Bash, I've never had Bash do that properly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Enable the `mark-symlinked-directories` option for [READLINE](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Init-File.html). There are few ways to do that:

1. Customize your *readline* by putting commands in an `.inputrc` file:

   - Create or edit `~/.inputrc` and add these lines:

     ```
     $include /etc/inputrc
     set mark-symlinked-directories on
     ```
   - Log-in/Log-out or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to reload the settings.
2. Customize your *readline* by putting commands in the `.bashrc` file (or in the `.profile` file):

   - Edit `~/.bashrc` and add this line:

     ```
     bind 'set mark-symlinked-directories on'
     ```
   - Log-in/Log-out or [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2518150/6543935) the file:

     ```
     source ~/.bashrc
     ```
3. Customize the *readline* for all users by creating a `.sh` file into the directory `/etc/profile.d`:

   - Create a file `/etc/profile.d/mark-symlinked-directories.sh` which should looks like:

     ```
     #!/bin/sh
     bind 'set mark-symlinked-directories on'
     ```

     Executable permissions to this file are not needed.
   - Log-in/Log-out. That's it.

Further reading:

- [READLINE section in the manual page of Bash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc27)
- [The source of the first two ways](https://superuser.com/a/271677/664884)
- [The source of the idea for the third way](https://askubuntu.com/a/866169/566421)

---

One simple way that I found is double <kbd>tab</kbd> for completion:

<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd>
 <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd>

The first <kbd>tab</kbd> will append `uments`, the second one will append `/` and the third will print the list of contained directories.

Comment: Related topic: https://askubuntu.com/a/599034/566421

Comment: Related topic: https://askubuntu.com/a/1202278/566421