# apt install - can't autocomplete package names (Docker)

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, package-management, auto-completion

It's the same error as in several other posts, but none of the solutions work for me.

I'm typing

```
apt-get install ar<TAB><TAB>
```

and there's not auto-completion. I'm using an Ubuntu-Docker:

```
#
# Ubuntu Dockerfile
#
# https://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu
#

# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install.
RUN \
  sed -i 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y upgrade && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
  apt-get install -y byobu curl git htop man unzip vim wget  openssh-server  && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN add-apt-repository main
RUN add-apt-repository universe
RUN add-apt-repository restricted
RUN add-apt-repository multiverse

RUN apt-get update

#ArangoDB stuff
RUN curl -OL https://download.arangodb.com/arangodb34/DEBIAN/Release.key && apt-key add - < Release.key
RUN echo 'deb https://download.arangodb.com/arangodb34/DEBIAN/ /' | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arangodb.list
RUN apt-get install apt-transport-https 
RUN apt-get update

# Set environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /root

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

which is working.

At first I couldn't use any auto-complete at all. Enabling the sections in the .bashrc allowed me to get the `install`, but now I'm stuck. What I did so far:

- `sudo apt-get update`

From [apt-get autocomplete package name is broken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86375/apt-get-autocomplete-package-name-is-broken)

`sudo apt-get install bash-completion`
Enabled this in the /etc/bash.bashrc:

```
# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

In the .bashrc I enabled:

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Still, no changes. Is there something docker-specific I have to put into consideration?

**Edit**:
Apparently it's a shell-issue. I installed `zsh`. In `zsh` it's working as supposed. 
I don't like to have this as a solution as I still don't understand why the regular shell refuses to work.

I have read about [enabling auto completion for apt-get install in docker (ubuntu 14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735189/enabling-auto-completion-for-apt-get-install-in-docker-ubuntu-14-04) - but frankly I don't quite get what the OP was doing to make it work.

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735189/enabling-auto-completion-for-apt-get-install-in-docker-ubuntu-14-04)? Looks like Docker does something specific to `apt` indeed!

Comment: @MrShunz - I read that already but couldn't make much sense out of it